# How to make vim-fake compatible with UltiSnips?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

For generating different placeholders like emails, names, and passwords, [vim-fake](https://github.com/tkhren/vim-fake) looks like a really useful tool. The problem is that I'm using [UltiSnips](https://github.com/sirver/ultisnips) and vim-fake is seemingly designed for [neosnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim)—the snippets can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tkhren/9fbc7227c2e9d2f4319c).
Taking this simple code which is written for neosnippet,

```
snippet fakeint
abbr    fake#int()
options word
    `fake#int()`
```

Is there any way to write something equivalent for UltiSnips environment? I already tried the following codes but got no results.

```
snippet fakeint
`fake#int()`
endsnippet
```

and also,

```
snippet fakeint
`echo fake#int()`
endsnippet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to use a Vimscript expression in UltiSnips is `` `!v ...` ``, so I think what you're looking for is:

```
snippet fakeint
`!v fake#int()`
endsnippet
```

See [`:help UltiSnips-vimscript`](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/96026a4df27899b9e4029dd3b2977ad2ed819caf/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L822) for all the details.

---

Note that you don't necessarily need to use a snippet manager to use the vim-fake functions, in Insert mode you could simply use `CTRL-R =` to insert the contents of an expression, then type the expression itself `fake#int()` (note that Tab completion should help you here) and finally press Enter.

This technique should allow you to insert the result of any Vimscript expressions in your text without having to configure them in your snippet manager.

Comment: Thank you so much. I find `fakeint` a little faster and easier to type than `fake#int()`. After writing all these snippets for UltiSnips, I would send my code on GitHub and provide a link here so that others could use it.